# jquery ajax call from select box

Tags: jquery

How to make ajax call from onchange event of select box using jquery? If anyone has a sample,
please post the code.

Answer (score 19):

the below code is based on spring mvc architecture,

```
$('#selectbox1').change(function() {
    var data = "";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : "controller mapping",
        data : "selectbox1_selectedvalue="+$(this).val(),
        async: false,
        success : function(response) {
            data = response;
            return response;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    });
    var string = data.message.split(",");
    var array = string.filter(function(e){return e;});
    var select = $('selectbox2');
    select.empty();
    $.each(array, function(index, value) {          
        select.append(
                $('<option></option>').val(value).html(value)
            );
    });
        $('#selectbox2').show();
});
```

inside the html, i use like below to display the selectbox2 values,

```
<tr>
    <select id="selectbox1">
        <option value="value1">value1</option><option value="value2">value2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selectbox2"></select>
</tr>
```

in the selectbox2, values are loaded from a controller using ajax call, in controller i return like below,

```
    List<String> listvalues = listService.retrieveAll(searchTerm); // searchTerm is a selected value from selectbox1
String dummy = "";
for(int i=0; i<listvalues.size(); i++)
{
    dummy += listvalues.get(i)+",";
}
MessageValue messageValue = new MessageValue(dummy);
return messageValue;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#selectboxid").change(function() {
  $.ajax({ url: "test.html", context: document.body, success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }});
});
```